# Pandas count event per day from join date

Tags: python, pandas, crosstab

I have this data frame:

```
name    event     join_date    created_at    
A       X         2020-12-01   2020-12-01
A       X         2020-12-01   2020-12-01
A       X         2020-12-01   2020-12-02
A       Y         2020-12-01   2020-12-02
B       X         2020-12-05   2020-12-05
B       X         2020-12-05   2020-12-07
C       X         2020-12-07   2020-12-08
C       X         2020-12-07   2020-12-09
...
```

I want to transform it into this data frame:

```
name   event    join_date    day_0   day_1    day_2 .... day_n
A      X        2020-12-01   2       1        0          0
A      Y        2020-12-01   0       1        0          0
B      X        2020-12-05   1       0        1          0
C      X        2020-12-07   0       1        1          0
...
```

the first rows mean that user A doing twice Event X on day_0 (first day he joins) and once on the first day and so on until day_n

For now, the result is like this:

```
name   event    join_date    day_0   day_1    day_2 .... day_n
A      X        2020-12-01   2       1        0          0
A      Y        2020-12-01   0       1        0          0
B      X        2020-12-05   1       0        1          0
C      X        2020-12-07   1       1        0          0
...
```

the code set the 2020-12-02 as day_0, not day_1 because there is no 2020-12-01 on A user with Y event

Comment: input data are not changed?

Comment: nope, it's similiar to this

Comment: @jezrael I think the problem is on df.d I have updated my post with the result of my df with your code

Comment: @jezrael I think I know the problem. I have updated my dataset with adding user C that don't have event on join date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First subtract all values `created_at` by first value per groups by  [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html).

Then use [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) first, add all possible datetimes by [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) by [`timedelta_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.timedelta_range.html) and then convert columns names by `range`:

```
df['d'] = df['created_at'].sub(df['join_date'])
print (df)
  name event  join_date created_at      d
0    A     X 2020-12-01 2020-12-01 0 days
1    A     X 2020-12-01 2020-12-01 0 days
2    A     X 2020-12-01 2020-12-02 1 days
3    A     Y 2020-12-01 2020-12-02 1 days
4    B     X 2020-12-05 2020-12-05 0 days
5    B     X 2020-12-05 2020-12-07 2 days
6    C     X 2020-12-07 2020-12-08 1 days
7    C     X 2020-12-07 2020-12-09 2 days

df1 = (df.pivot_table(index=['name','event','join_date'], 
                     columns='d', 
                     aggfunc='size', 
                     fill_value=0)
         .reindex(pd.timedelta_range(df['d'].min(), df['d'].max()), 
                  axis=1, 
                  fill_value=0))
df1.columns = [f'day_{i}' for i in range(len(df1.columns))]
df1 = df1.reset_index()
print (df1)
  name event  join_date  day_0  day_1  day_2
0    A     X 2020-12-01      2      1      0
1    A     Y 2020-12-01      0      1      0
2    B     X 2020-12-05      1      0      1
3    C     X 2020-12-07      0      1      1
```

Comment: I think the value of user B is false. the value is on day_0 and day_2, not day_4 and day_6

Comment: in my case, the name A with event Y the result should be 0, 1, 0. not 1, 0, 0

Comment: my pleasure. if you don't mind, what if I want to fill only 1 (active) and 0 (not active or no event on a certain day). so the value is not count event but 1 or 0

Comment: sorry I don't understand how to use it

Comment: TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Comment: I think 'df['d'] = df['created_at'].sub(s)' is not solution if there is no event when the user joined. For example if B dont have event on 2020-12-01, 2020-12-02 will be the day_0, not day_1

Comment: What I encounter is the 2nd row or user A with Y event the result is 1, 0, 0 not 0, 1, 0 because there is no A user with event Y that happen in 2020-12-01 so the code set the day_0 is on 2020-12-02

Comment: Alright I will try to update. maybe the solution df['d'] is different from join_date and created_at. but when I apply this, the value of day_0 is move to day_80

Comment: @OctavianWR - Not sure what is problem, but `d` column is different like you mentioned in question, in real data are datetimes sorted? If not, try `s = df.groupby(['name'])['created_at'].transform('min')`

Comment: the join_date or the created_at that have to be sorted?

Comment: @OctavianWR - My idea was first value of `created_at` was also minimal values per group, but I think if use `min` instead `first` is should working

Comment: @OctavianWR - I think solution is simplier, first line od code is `df['d'] = df['created_at'].sub(df['join_date'])`